# Is there any scriptural reference that there is radha naam is ra kaar and madhav naam in m kaar of ram naam?

Tags: ramayana

Is there any scriptural reference of radha madhav name in ram naam ?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.